# Linear deformations of a morphism between stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, stacks, cotangent-complex

Given smooth algebraic stacks $\mathcal{X}$, $\mathcal{Y}$ what are the linear deformations $\operatorname{Def}^1(f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y})$ of a morphism $f:\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$?

In scheme theory we have the linear deformations
$$
\operatorname{Def}^1(f:X \to Y) = H^0(X, f^{*}T_Y).
$$
On the stack $\mathcal{Y}$ we have a two-term tangent complex $\mathbb{T}_\mathcal{Y}$, so by emulating the scheme theory case I would make the prediction;
$$
\operatorname{Def}^1(f:\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}) = H^0(\mathcal{X}, f^{*}\mathbb{T}_\mathcal{Y}). 
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the set of isomorphism classes of deformations, almost by definition of the tangent complex.

Comment: I am struggling to see the connection, could you explain this with some details?

Comment: If the $1$-morphism $f$ is representable (by algebraic spaces), then this follows from the article of Martin Olsson, "Deformation theory of representable morphisms of algebraic stacks."  See also Remark 1.8 in that article.